# How do I approximate a timeseries with a sum of sin and cos functions?

Tags: r, predictive-models, fourier-transform

I have a time series and I am trying to approximate it using an equation of the type:

`y = A + B*sin(2*pi*x/n) + C*cos(2*pi*x/m) + D*sin(2*pi*x/q) + ...`

The questions is how to find the parameters A, B, C, D, n, m, q, etc... Finding these values manually is obviously a very cumbersome process. I thought this would be a relatively simple problem for FFT, but I am getting nowhere (never done it before!).

My code (in R) is this:

```
value.ft <- fft(out.df$VALUE)
value.terms <- 4

fft.value <- rep(0, length(value.ft))
fft.value[1:value.terms] <- value.ft[1:value.terms]

value.approx <- Re(fft(fft.value, inverse=TRUE)) / length(out.df$VALUE)
```

with the following data.frame (`out.df`) as input:

```
structure(list(out.df.SEC = c(0, 300, 600, 900, 3000, 3300, 3600, 
3900, 4200, 4500, 6600, 6900, 7200, 7500, 7800, 8100, 10200, 
10500, 10800, 11100, 11400, 13500, 13800, 14100, 14400, 14700, 
15000, 17100, 17400, 17700, 18000, 18300, 18600, 20700, 21000, 
21300, 21600, 21900, 22200, 24000, 24300, 24600, 24900, 25200, 
25500, 27600, 27900, 28200, 28500, 28800, 29100, 31200, 31500, 
31800, 32100, 32400, 32700, 34500, 34800, 35100, 35400, 35700, 
36000, 38100, 38400, 38700, 39000, 39300, 39600, 41700, 42000, 
42300, 42600, 42900, 43200, 45300, 45600, 45900, 46200, 46500, 
48600, 48900, 49200, 49500, 49800, 50100, 52200, 52500, 52800, 
53100, 53400, 53700, 55800, 56100, 56400, 56700, 57000, 59100, 
59400, 59700, 60000, 60300, 60600, 62700, 63000, 63300, 63600, 
63900, 64200, 66300, 66600, 66900, 67200, 67500, 69600, 69900, 
70200, 70500, 70800, 71100, 73200, 73500, 73800, 74100, 74400, 
74700, 76800, 77100, 77400, 77700, 78000, 78300, 80100, 80400, 
80700, 81000, 81300, 81600), out.df.VALUE = c(4.858, 4.938, 4.724, 
4.45, 3.70666666666667, 3.9, 3.83, 3.784, 3.704, 3.6775, 3.4375, 
3.368, 3.394, 3.552, 3.728, 3.65, 3.46, 3.444, 3.392, 3.378, 
3.444, 3.34, 3.328, 3.246, 3.192, 3.212, 3.23, 3.6475, 3.484, 
3.418, 3.556, 3.778, 3.80666666666667, 4.278, 4.428, 4.62, 4.886, 
4.872, 4.99, 6.7, 6.132, 5.318, 4.722, 4.556, 4.32, 4.4125, 4.442, 
4.376, 4.43, 4.55, 4.58, 4.114, 4.026, 4.11, 3.994, 3.97, 4.13, 
3.98, 4.006, 3.918, 3.75, 3.734, 3.652, 3.81, 3.814, 3.816, 3.674, 
3.592, 3.78, 3.608, 3.446, 3.474, 3.564, 3.252, 3.17, 3.1, 3.044, 
2.818, 2.868, 2.564, 2.65, 2.732, 2.76, 2.646, 2.608, 2.6075, 
3.0975, 2.794, 2.962, 2.848, 2.276, 2.15, 2.326, 2.19, 2.396, 
2.072, 2.758, 2.73666666666667, 2.66, 2.726, 2.556, 2.61, 2.964, 
3.125, 3.014, 2.966, 2.794, 2.95, 2.91666666666667, 3.054, 3.148, 
3.068, 2.97, 3.08, 2.9, 2.88, 2.904, 2.976, 3.148, 3.078, 3, 
2.888, 2.914, 2.774, 2.708, 2.59666666666667, 3.008, 2.976, 3.152, 
3.102, 2.954, 2.96, 2.895, 2.854, 2.832, 2.908, 2.886, 3.026)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -138L))
```

The result looks like this, and I think it is not nearly as good as it could be:

[image: Plot of the original data and the FFT fit]

Changing the variable `value.terms` does not improve the outcome, and tend to result in overfitting. Is FFT the right approach here, or am I overcomplicating things?

**EDIT:** just to clarify, the objective is not an exact reproduction of the data but an approximation, whose equation can be used for other calculations. In the example, if the peak around 30k seconds and the two troughs around 15k and 50k seconds were just a bit more pronounced it'd be enough.

Comment: fft should be fine. linear regression should also work (like fft with a fixed periodicity).  I suspect the issue is that your data is not periodic, you have a jump between the value at 80000 and the value at 0.

Answer (score 0):

I find it odd to use time (your x variable) as explanation of y. Specially if your time-series is not vanishing after a while...

What I see more often about time-series is using past to predict present. I tried using one lag of your y variable to explain itself, also know as AR(1). Results seem better and I am sharing it here. I am not sure if this answers your question but I had fun doing it.

```
#Make your code more generic
dt = as.data.table(a)
setnames(dt, "out.df.VALUE", "y")
setnames(dt, "out.df.SEC", "x")

dt[, lagy := shift(y, type = "lag", n = 1)]

model <- lm(y ~ lagy, dt)

int <- coef(model)[[1]]
slope <- coef(model)[[2]]

dt[, prediction := int + slope * lagy]
dt[, error := y - prediction]
score <- dt[2:.N, mean(error^2)]

plot_ly(dt, x = ~x, y = ~y, type = 'scatter', mode = "markers") %>%
    add_trace(x = ~x, y = ~prediction, type = 'scatter', mode = "lines")
```

You can play with logs (improves prediction slightly), you can include more lags as explanatory variables etc.

[image]

Comment: The sin/cos fitting does help when there are diurnal or other cyclic variations to account for. That said, your model does seem to fit this particular data set pretty well. It seems like you have used some packages beyond what's in base R, however, so to help others reproduce this please edit the answer to specify what packages you used.

Comment: "*I find it odd to use time (your x variable) as explanation of y. Specially if your time-series is not vanishing after a while...*" Makes sense if you expect the series to be a bounded monotonic function of time, but let me add that there are other cases.